# How to resolve the error code "2010010 " while running HMS Audio Kit Application?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I am running HMS Audio Kit application getting an error code **2010010**. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is it by any chance this code:

> ERROR_MODULE_NOT_PRESET_HSF : 2010010 : HMS Core (APK) is not supported by the operating system of the device.

as found [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/error-code-0000001050752777-V5) ?

Then, as per documentation, the solution is: **Use a Huawei device that meets the requirements and try again.**

If you check the requirements on [this page](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/introduction-0000001050749665-V5):

1. Device brand: Huawei,
2. Device type: Android phone and tablet running Android 6.0 (EMUI 4.0) or later
3. HMS Core (APK) Version: 5.0.0.300 or later